# Windows claims incorrect password for AAD users, won't give other options

Tags: windows-11, azure-activedirectory, windows-11-v22h2

I have joined newly installed Windows 11 Enterprise 22H2 with latest updates into newly formed M365 tenant and also enrolled Intune. I was about to setup Hello for Business, but relevant section in Settings app would not load, so decided to reboot. After reboot, unable to log in: claims that the password is wrong (definitely not so). I am also unable to choose or verify UPN, which seems standard behavior for Win11. Installation is responsive to Intune, which has enabled me to try some tricks:

1. Enable web-based login authentication. I get the corresponding option on login screen, but the button won't do anything.
2. Removed device primary user on Intune with the hope that I could at least choose another account. No effect. Tried assigning another primary user. Still no effect.
3. Ensured that Windows should not log in the last user and lock after reboot.
   Tenant AAD authentication settings were security-oriented at the time this came about. I relaxed those substantially in the hope that Windows would then find authentication method that suites it. No effect.

I encountered this problem on the same device in another tenant without Intune. Having to do clean reinstall due to that prompted me to create new test tenant where Intune would manage client devices and prevent any mishaps... did not turn quite as expected. Before reinstall I was able to force local administrator account on and log into it, but lost ability to log in as AAD user. Password reset through AAD management is not useful (only reflected in logins other than that to Windows).

I'm pretty sure that erasing any cached login credentials and being able to enter the domain user name would be helpful, but there's no obvious way to achieve even that. Getting Windows web login to work would be even better. I'm quite bruised by this.

Comment: The fact the button does nothing suggests a bad install but the fact it presumably worked that initially suggests a policy conflict. Difficult to nearly impossible to diagnose without know which policies the machine is enforcing

Comment: Are there instructions how to setup web sign-in method in AAD tenant without any federations? It also strikes odd to me that changing AAD user accounts display name and adding a profile photo through Azure management console are not reflected on Windows login screen.